# Deleting commits from a branch in which other branchs are merged

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-reset

I have three branches - *A(branch I am working on), B, C.*

The commit history of branches B and C looks like this

*Branch B*

- commit b2
- commit b1

*Branch C*

- commit c2
- commit c1

I have merged these branches into *Branch A*, So commit history for *A* looks like this

- commit a2
- commit c2
- commit c1
- commit b2
- commit b1
- commit a1

I want to reset my branch A to commit a1 using `git reset --hard a1`. If I do this does commit b1,b2 and c1, c2 gets removed from branches B and C as well or they get removed from only branch A?

Comment: You should try out ```git rebase -i <hash before what you want to delete>```. You can then change “pick” to “drop” and save and you should be able to drop the commit. Not making this an answer bc there could be some issues depending on what commit you’re trying to drop, but you should definitely try that. If you run into issues don’t forget ```git rebase --abort``` and ```git reflog```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hard reset on `Branch A` will affect only that branch. The the other branches will remain unaffected.

To answer your question - After a hard reset of `Branch A` with (`git reset --hard a1`), the commits `b1` and `b2` will remain in `Branch B` and the commits `c1` and `c2` will remain in `Branch C`.

Answer (score 1):

No, `git reset --hard a1` will not change any of the commits on branches B or C. However you will lose the work in commit `a2` unless it is saved elsewhere.